# Need to add empty choice to existing valuelistqueryset for django choicefield

Tags: django, django-forms, choicefield

I need to add the empty choice value in existing valuelistqueryset for below choicefield in my form in Django similat to `modelchoicefield("-------------")`. Can anyone help me with this?

```
hardness = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Description.objects.filter(variable="hardness", paradigm='206209').values_list('dvalue', flat=True).distinct().order_by('dvalue'))
```

@jghyllebert Thanks for your reply. But in this case I need to convert modelchoicefield to choicefield. And I need the solution for `choicefield`. Sorry if i was not clear about it. I tried `empty_label` and `empty_value` in choice field but the form goes in error.

```
rimplan = forms.ChoiceField(
    required=False, 
    empty_value = '---',
    choices=Description.objects.filter(
        variable="rimplan", 
        paradigm='206209').values_list(
            'dvalue', 
            flat=True).distinct().order_by('dvalue'))
```

Thus, I have implemented this solution which work perfectly fine.

```
EXTSURCOLOR_DESCRIPTIONS = Description.objects.filter(
    variable="exteriorsurfacecolor", 
    paradigm='206209') 

EXTSURCOLOR_CHOICES = [('', '---')] 

EXTSURCOLOR_CHOICES.extend(
    EXTSURCOLOR_DESCRIPTIONS.values_list(
        "dvalue", 
        "dvalue").distinct().order_by('dvalue')) 

exteriorsurfacecolor = forms.ChoiceField(choices = EXTSURCOLOR_CHOICES)
```

I just wanted to know if there is any better solution out there.

Comment: Is there something about the empty value that will be displayed if you set `required=False` that isn't working for you?  You can't literally insert it into the queryset, but it'll add it to the choices offered for the field.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) which you can use to set a custom value for the empty choice option.

```
hardness = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Description.objects.filter(variable="hardness", paradigm='206209').values_list('dvalue', flat=True).distinct().order_by('dvalue'),
    empty_label='Not applicable', #for instance
    required=False
)
```

Following the docs:

> Note that if a ModelChoiceField is required and has a default initial value, no empty choice is created (regardless of the value of empty_label).

Comment: @jghyllebert Thanks for your reply. But in this case I need to convert modelchoicefield to choicefield. And I need the solution for choicefield. Sorry if i was not clear about it. I tried empty_label and empty_value in choice field but the form goes in error.
rimplan = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, empty_value = '---', choices=Description.objects.filter(variable="rimplan", paradigm='206209').values_list('dvalue', flat=True).distinct().order_by('dvalue'))

Comment: Thus, I have implemented this solution which work perfectly fine.

EXTSURCOLOR_DESCRIPTIONS = Description.objects.filter(variable="exteriorsurfacecolor", paradigm='206209')
    EXTSURCOLOR_CHOICES = [('', '---')]
    EXTSURCOLOR_CHOICES.extend(EXTSURCOLOR_DESCRIPTIONS.values_list("dvalue", "dvalue").distinct().order_by('dvalue'))
    exteriorsurfacecolor = forms.ChoiceField(choices = EXTSURCOLOR_CHOICES)

I just wanted to know if there is any better solution out there.

Comment: could post this code in your question? It's quite hard to read now.